# How to implement exact match query in Grafana

Tags: elasticsearch, grafana, elasticsearch-query, elasticsearch-analyzers

I am trying to implement some dashboard in Grafana on top of ElasticSearch index based on some user selection from dropdown ($Key). My dropdown Grafana variable reads `$Key` and I have mentioned the `query` to pull data for that `$Key` is like `fields.key:$Key`. Now the issue I am facing is , Grafana `query string` uses `analyze_wildcard:true` and I want `exact match` , is there a way to do it in Grafana.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you go ahead and edit this file you can change the analyze_wildcard flag to false.  I haven't quite figured out why this is hardcoded to true.

[image: file to edit]